# The sum of reciprocals of odd numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have a question that I've been thinking for a while now.

*Can you find a set of distinct positive odd integers* $n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k$ *for some finite  positive integer* $k$ *such that* $\left(\frac{1}{n_1} + \frac{1}{n_2} + \ldots + \frac{1}{n_k} \right)$ *is a positive integer as well?*

This statement obviously holds if we allow $n_1 \ldots n_k$ to be even. I'd be glad if you can recommend some articles that study this particular problem.

Comment: Found by hand in under 2 minutes: $1/3 + 1/5 + 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/15 + 1/21 + 1/23 + 1/35 + 1/63 + 1/105 + 1/1035 = 1$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, you can choose the $n_i$ so that the sum is $1$: see the discussion at http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/odd-one.html

Comment: For some reason I can't open this webpage. Is it just me?